# How does one protect his AJAX views with Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm using a *private* view in my Django project for an AJAX request.

```python
def HereIsSomeJSON(request, label):
    if not request.method == "POST":
        raise PermissionDenied
    # Here is the job of my AJAX, basically feeding a JSON
    json = {...}

    return HttpResponse(json, "application/json")
```

Using JavaScript, I request for the AJAX with jQuery as so:

```js
function FeedMeWithJSON() {
    // Django needs his Cross-Site Request Forgery token to welome POST datas
    oPostDatas = {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
    };
    jQuery.post("/url/to/HereIsSomeJSON", oPostDatas, function(oData, sStatus) {
        // Here is the job to be done with the fetched JSON
    }, "json");
}
```

Everything works just fine thanks to the `request.method` verification I do in the view. The user isn't able to manually (by entering my AJAX url in his browser) access to my view.

However, as I will need more AJAX views I was wondering if I was doing the right thing. So I thought of creating a custom Django decorator which I could use above every one of my AJAX views.

Is is the good way of protecting my *private* views ? And if so, how do I do it ?

Thanks,

## Edit

---

Apparently, this was not clear enough. I am using a Django view to do an AJAX request. But I don't want the user to be able to type in the URL to read database contents. I know one could always use `curl` or something similar to send POST datas and thus bypassing my thing, even though he would have to send the right `{% csrf_token %}`.

Plus, in *a near future* the *login* feature will be implemented and I will add the `@login_required` decorator.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know why you say a user can't manually execute your query. You deny permission to `POST`s requests, manually entering a url in a web browser sends a `GET` request, which, by the code I'm reading, will execute the view fine. Am I right?

Comment: what do you mean with 'protect'? In this case you are only limiting your view to GET requests and not actually enforcing any kind of protection. So the question is what dou you want to prevent the user from doing?

Comment: Paulo Bu and armonge, the code does in fact raise an exception for GET requests, since the conditional is "if not request.method=='POST'". Note the 'not' in the conditional. In prose, this is "If the request method is NOT a POST request, raise a PermissionDenied exception."

Comment: @PauloBu Please see Chris' comment.

Comment: @armonge I only want the user not to be able to type the URL in his browser and thus read the database content. Datas are not sensitive, but I feel better managing it this way :).

Comment: Oh! Sorry, my bad, just read the code to fast! Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that requiring POST is not enough, one could possibly cheat using `curl` for example.

That is why a custom decorator is - in my opinion - the way to go.

```py
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest


def require_AJAX(function):
    """Return a bad request instance if the view is not using AJAX
    function -- the view
    """

    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)

    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

This decorator does actually less than @stalk's but this what I needed.

Comment: How would you pass the correct CSRF token if doing a POST via `curl`? Chris Lawlor's answer is more than enough.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach of requiring POST for your ajax views is basically OK, and there is an [existing decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/) to handle it:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
def my_view(request):
    # I can assume now that only POST requests make it this far
    # ...
    pass
```

Also, there is an easier way to handle adding CSRF tokens to your jQuery AJAX calls, documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax). The basic idea is that you read the CSRF token from the cookie, and use the `beforeSend` option in `$.ajaxSetup` to add it to your all of your `$.ajax` calls (including shortcut syntax like `$.post`).

Since this code isn't relying on template variables, it doesn't have to be in an inline `<script>` tag.

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@armonge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407762/armonge) said, just checking for POST method doesn't do any protection. Suppose you need some checks, that user is registered and maybe have some permissions or needed properties. For this purpose, such decorator can be used (probably needs to be customized):

```
def apply_permissions(view_func):
    def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # it is possible to add some other checks, that return booleans
        # or do it in a separate `if` statement
        # for example, check for some user permissions or properties
        permissions = [
            request.is_ajax(),
            request.method == "POST",
            request.user.is_authenticated()
        ]
        if not all(permissions):
            raise PermissionDenied
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped_view


@apply_permissions
def HereIsSomeJSON(request, label):
    # your code here without any permissions checks

    # Here is the job of my AJAX, basically feeding a JSON
```