# Django: login user and refresh on same page without defining a template?

Tags: django, templates, view, authentication, refresh

I'm trying to use a bootstrap drop-down sign in form to have users login. I'm able to hard code my username and password and authenticate just fine but I'm trying to have a user login without going to a login screen. Here is my code:

Template:
I use action to call the logUserIn url so that the form can post to that view.

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li><a> Welcome {{ user.first_name }} </a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'caesarWorkflowApp.views.logUserOut' %}">Log Out</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          {% else %}
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
              <form action="{% url 'caesarWorkflowApp.views.logUserIn' %}" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" size="30" />
                <input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" size="30" />
                <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />
                <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
            {% endif %}
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        </ul>
```

[image]

URLS:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'caesarWorkflowApp.views.home', name='default'),
    url(r'^$', 'caesarWorkflowApp.views.logUserIn'),
    url(r'^$', 'caesarWorkflowApp.views.logUserOut'),
)
```

VIEWS:
Then I have this view for login which doesn't work because console never even print 'enter' even though the form is posting successfully. Am I posting wrong? Calling the wrong action? **Does anyone know how to create a login/logout view without creating a template for it so that it just refreshes/redirects to the home page?**

```
def logUserIn(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'enter'
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            # the password verified for the user
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                print("User is valid, active and authenticated")

            else:
                print("The password is valid, but the account has been disabled!")
        else:
            # the authentication system was unable to verify the username and password
            print("The username and password were incorrect.")

    response = render_to_response('home.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return response
```

I also want the page to not ask me if I want to reload since the it's post form and I believe this is the solution in case anyone is interested in that: [Stop browsers asking to resend form data on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327236/stop-browsers-asking-to-resend-form-data-on-refresh)

Thank you!

Comment: What you are looking for is called AJAX. Will soon post a working example, get a beer ;].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get AJAX working so I just came up with this solution:

TEMPLATE:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li><a> Welcome, {{ user.first_name }} </a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="/logout/">Log Out</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          {% else %}
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
              <form id="form-login" action="/" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" size="30" />
                <input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" size="30" />
                <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />
                <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
```

URLS:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'caesarWorkflowApp.views.home', name='default'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'caesarWorkflowApp.views.logUserIn'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'caesarWorkflowApp.views.logUserOut'),
)
```

VIEWS:

```
def logUserIn(request):
    print 'enter'
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        # the password verified for the user
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            print("User is valid, active and authenticated")

        else:
            print("The password is valid, but the account has been disabled!")
    else:
        # the authentication system was unable to verify the username and password
        print("The username and password were incorrect.")

    response = render_to_response('home.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return response

def logUserOut(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Works perfectly and really nice looking! =)

Comment: This is not AJAX, you are loading a new page each time if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: From the 404 error you gave me in my answer's comments, I get that you are going to the URL (literally): `/{% url 'login-submit' %}`, so yeah 404 obviously. This was happening because your URL tag was not translated.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called AJAX. I always used [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to handle AJAX requests as it makes the job way easier.

Here is how I usually proceed:

1. Create an `ajax` application inside my Django project to keep my AJAX views and URLs away from the rest of my code (also, I like to re'use my apps. from one project to another)
2. Code the AJAX view and its URL inside the `ajax` application
3. Apply the AJAX request to my forms using jQuery

### The template

```html
<form id="form-login" action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<!-- Put your form here -->
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

### The JavaScript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form-login").submit(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            "data":    $(this).serialize(),
            "type":    $(this).attr("method"),
            "url":     "{% url 'login-submit' %}",
            "success": function(response) {
                switch(response.code) {
                    // Do what you want with the received response
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

### The AJAX URL

```py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^ajax/login/submit/$', 'path.to.login_submit', name='login-submit'),
)
```

### The AJAX view

```py
@require_AJAX
def login_submit(request, label):
    # Code here the logging logic 
    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({'code':'42'}), content_type='application/json')
    return response
```

**Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18213333/1824222) for the `require_AJAX` decorator.**

I often use AJAX when it comes to submit form (not only logging), so I apply the above JavaScript code to all my forms (with `$("form").submit(...);`). But I then need to let the view know which form I am posting. Here is how I proceed in case you need it:

- First your URL should welcome an argument (the form's id for me)
- Then the associated view would be able to know which case to handle with the corresponding label

Comment: I'm getting this error: [12/Jul/2013 12:40:15] "POST /%7B%%20url%20'login-submit'%20%%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 2735

Comment: 404 means it didn't find your view, which version of Django are you using ?

Comment: @MathieuMarques Nice work. I believe this should be the accepted answer... let's see how implementing this myself goes.

Comment: @user1850672, Thanks ! I now realise I made a mistake, which was the `@require_POST`. In fact, protecting the view from anything else than POST doesn't actually fit. Modified with `@require_AJAX`, [a decorator I wrote myself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18213333/1824222).

Comment: This looks good but the page keeps reloading after I hit submit, preventing me from actually making use of this. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: @FLOWMEEN I'm missing some context here, but this post should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit.