# jQuery post is redirecting page

Tags: jquery

Today I learned some jQuery.

```
<script>    
$('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
email=document.mc-embedded-subscribe-form.EMAIL.value;
$.post( "email.php", {email});
$('#fadeout').fadeOut(500);
$('#fadein').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
});
</script>
```

This is a script I'm running upon the event of a user submitting a form. The problem I'm having is that as soon as the form is submitted I get redirected to email.php, whereas I want to stay on the initial webpage. If I remove the line

```
$.post( "email.php", {email});
```

The rest works as expected. email.php works fine, it simply saves the email. What can I do to stop the redirect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit

Comment: Look for errors in your browser's consol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's an error in your `$.post()` line the `e.preventDefault()` is not kicking in. Edit your code to the following:

```
$('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    email = $('[name=EMAIL]',this).val();
    $.post( "email.php", {email:email}, function() {
        $('#fadeout').fadeOut(500);
        $('#fadein').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I felt that this was in the spirit of the question and pointed out the error.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to post specific value from client side to server than its better to use $.ajax method then $.post i.e:

```
<script>    

    $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    email=document.mc-embedded-subscribe-form.EMAIL.value;
    $.ajax({

        url:"email.php";
        data: email;
        success:function(){
           $('#fadeout').fadeOut(500);
           $('#fadein').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

$.ajax post specific value or values to server side without redirection of the page.