# I'm trying to create a calculator with inputs, but it works wrong, why?

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, calculator, reset

I'm trying to create a calculator with HTML inputs, but it not working, when I'm  push on "Calculate" it's show me right answer and immediately refreshing page, but I'm don't want to refresh 
this is my code, why it not working?

`document.getElementById("calc").onclick = function() {myFunction()};`

```
function myFunction() {
 if (isNaN(document.getElementById("num1").value) || isNaN(document.getElementById("num2").value)) {
   document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = "Please enter number!";

 }
else {
  switch (document.getElementById("opr").value) {
    case "+": 
      document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value) +      parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value) ;
      break;
    case "-": document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value) -   parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value) ;
      break;
    case "*": document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value) * parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value) ;
      break;
    case "/": document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value) / parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value) ;
      break;
    default: document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = "Something went wrong, please try again";
      break;
  } 
  }  
  }
```

Comment: My best guess is that the inputs are in a form.

Comment: whatever the problem, it's not in the code you've posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit

Comment: can you show the code from where you are taking the input? it is possible that you have a form, and because of that it is refreshing.

Comment: thanks very much, the problem was form, but without form i can't reset, therefor i put "Value" out of <form>