# Each time I click button page refreshes

Tags: javascript, html

Title virtually says it all. Each time I click calculate button the page just refreshes. I added the stopPropagation and preventDefault which worked on my other button on a different page, however in this situation they don't seem to work. Any thoughts?

JS:

```
/******** Loan Balance Constructor *********/
function LoanBalance(mLoanAmt, mIntRate, nMonths, mMonthlyPmt){
//Declarations
this.loanAmount = mLoanAmt;
this.interestRate = mIntRate;
this.numbOfMonths = nMonths;
this.monthlyPayment = mMonthlyPmt;

//Calculates Remaining Balance
this.calculateRemaining = function(){
    console.log(this.loanAmount);
    console.log(this.interestRate);
    console.log(this.numbOfMonths);
    console.log(this.monthlyPayment);
        //COME BACK TO FIX THE FORMULA 
var remainingBalance = this.loanAmount*(Math.pow(1+this.interestRate, this.numbOfMonths) -
                        (this.monthlyPayment*(Math.pow(1 + this.interestRate, this.numbOfMonths) - 1) / this.interestRate));

return remainingBalance;
    }
    return this.calculateRemaining()
}

function newBalanceObject(e){
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();

var balanceObject = new LoanBalance(document.getElementById("loanAmount").value, document.getElementById("interestRate").value, 
                                    document.getElementById("numMonthsPaid").value, document.getElementById("sliderDuration").value);

var result = balanceObject.calculateRemaining();
document.getElementById("remainingBalanceTag").innerHTML = "Your remaining balance is: " + "$" + result.toFixed(2);
```

}

HTML:

```
        <div id="remainingBalance">
        <h1 class="text-center">Loan Balance Calculator</h1>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="loanAmount">Loan Amount:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="loanAmount">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="interestRate">Interest Rate:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="interestRate" placeholder="Please enter number as a decimal">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="numMonthsPaid">Number of Months Paid: </label>
                <input id="numMonthsPaid" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="600" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="300">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sliderDuration">Loan Duration: </label>
                <input id="sliderDuration" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="600" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="300"/>
            </div>
            <button id="calcButton" class="btn btn-default">Calculate</button>
        </form>
        <h1 class="text-center" id="remainingBalanceTag"></h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where do you call your JS functions? You need to have an event listener for click on your `#calcButton`, right?

Comment: I've added an event listener sorry for not including it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop form refreshing page on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit)

Answer (score 0):

The form is getting submitted by default. You need to intercept the [submission event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) and stop the default's browser action.

Since you haven't specified the `action` on the `form` element, it's simply refreshing the page, because it doesn't know where to send the data to.

Here's a sample code which shows how to intercept and stop *all* forms fom being submitted by the browser. Adjust it according to your setup so you only prevent submission of the forms that you want prevented.

```
Array.from(document.forms).forEach(form => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => e.preventDefault())
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to JS and don't fully understand what you are saying. I don't understand why you are using Array or a .forEach and Adjust what according to my setup?  I'm adding this event listener to my form?