# How to dynamically display a textbox and make it required based on radiobox selected in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

So, I am learning basics of Jquery. I have two radioboxes and one textbox, and if "first" radiobox is selected hide the textbox and if "Second" radiobox is selected I want to show a textbox and make it as "Required Field" too at the same time. I tried some solution, but I think I overcomplicated it.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input class="js-radio" id="SelectedRoleType" name="SelectedRoleType" type="radio" value="JobSeeker"> Job Seeker
    <input class="js-radio" id="SelectedRoleType" name="SelectedRoleType" type="radio" value="Referrer"> Referrar
</div>      
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Steps I followed to achieve to my solution.

1. added one class "MyTextBoxClass" to the textbox - [Not sure if it was necessary]
2. Added "display to none"
3. Added one class "MyRadioClass" to the radiobox - [Not sure if it was necessary]

   `<div>
   <input class="MyRadioClass" id="SelectedRoleType" name="SelectedRoleType" type="radio" value="JobSeeker"> Job Seeker
   <input class="MyRadioClass" id="SelectedRoleType" name="SelectedRoleType" type="radio" value="Referrer"> Referrar
   </div>`
4. Added a "CHANGE" event on that MyRadioClass
5. On change checked the value of the radiobox,
6. If it is second one then removed the Style attribute so that NONE is taken out and added "Required Attribute"
7. If it is the first checkbox then **add display as none**

```js
$('.MyRadioClass').on('change', function () {
    if($('input[name=SelectedRoleType]:checked').val() == "Referrer")
    {
        $('.MyTextBoxClass').removeAttr("style");
        $('.MyTextBoxClass #Email').attr('required','required');
    }
    else {
        $('.MyTextBoxClass').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-10 MyRadioClass">
    <input class="js-radio" id="SelectedRoleType" name="SelectedRoleType" type="radio" value="JobSeeker"> Job Seeker
    <input class="js-radio" id="SelectedRoleType" name="SelectedRoleType" type="radio" value="Referrer"> Referrar
</div>
        
<div class="col-md-10 MyTextBoxClass" style="display:none;">
    <input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

**Question 1**. When I submit the form the "Required" attribute is not getting appended. I am able to submit the form without putting any value in the textbox.

**Question 2**. Is there a more sleek way of doing what I wanted to achieve?

My Actual Code:

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <div class="form-group MyRadioClass">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedRoleType, "JobSeeker", new { @class="js-radio"}) Job Seeker
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedRoleType,"Referrer", new { @class="js-radio"}) Referrar
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group MyTextBoxClass" style = "display:none" ">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>

}
<button class="btn btn-info">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-facebook"></i>
    facebook
</button>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script>
    $('.MyRadioClass').on('change', function () {
        if($('input[name=SelectedRoleType]:checked').val() == "Referrer")
        {
            $('.MyTextBoxClass').show();
            $('.MyTextBoxClass input').attr('required', true);

        }
        else {
            $('.MyTextBoxClass').hide();
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: try using https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: have you tried with `$('.MyTextBoxClass #Email').attr('required','required');`

Comment: Corrected your code! Play it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your using the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` libraries for client side validation. These are not compatible with HTML-5 validation (which the `required` attribute is), and the `jquery.validate.js` modifies your `<form>` tag to add the `novalidate` attribute so your `required` attribute is ignored.

In order to get both client and server side validation you need to apply a conditional validation attribute. There are plenty of example of these on SO, or you could use [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` attribute. In addition, if you want to learn to write your own I recommend reading [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2).

Using the foolproof attribute, your model property will be

```
[RequiredIf("SelectedRoleType", "Referrer", ErrorMessage = "...")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

If you select the 2nd radio button (for 'Referrer') and leave the `Email` control empty, you submit action will be cancelled and the error message will be displayed in the view.

Then to show/hide the elements associated with the email property, your script should be

```
$('.MyRadioClass .js-radio').on('change', function () {
    if($('input[name=SelectedRoleType]:checked').val() == "Referrer") {
        $('.MyTextBoxClass').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.MyTextBoxClass').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong way. You should have a clear understanding of jQuery selectors.

`$('.MyTextBoxClass').css('required');` wouldn't work as you're selecting an HTML element, not the input field.

Secondly, `.css()` is not what you're looking for. Do something like this to make it work:

`$(".MyTextBoxClass input").attr("required", true);`

And, to show and hide your text input, I recommend using jQuery's `show()` and `hide()` methods.

So your code would look like this:

```
$('.MyRadioClass').on('change', function () {
    if($('input[name=SelectedRoleType]:checked').val() == "Referrer")
    {
        $('.MyTextBoxClass').show();
        $('.MyTextBoxClass input').attr('required', true);
    }
    else {
        $('.MyTextBoxClass').hide();
        $('.MyTextBoxClass input').removeAttr('required');
    }
});
```

If it still doesn't work, let me know.

EDIT: Remove validate tag from your `form` tag and use jQuery's submit event to solve the issue. Here's a link you may want to read [Stop form refreshing page on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit)

e.g.,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('yourForm').removeAttr("novalidate");
});

$('yourForm').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //DO STUFF
});
```

Comment: This is the inspect element output that is getting generated now. `<div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" required="required" type="text" value="">
        </div>`

Comment: Still when I submit i do not see any error/validation message. Why so? Why am I still able to submit. Reqired = reuired. why it is not doing what it is supose to do.

Comment: Is there any additional steps/plugin required?

Comment: Yes. This is what you want? Now, if you will submit form without text in this input, it won't submit. Also, I would like to see how you're submitting form. That will help me see if you're doing things right or not.

Comment: Please post your form submit code. No plugins required. Improvements might be needed.

Comment: What do you see in HTML rendered in console. Is `<form>` tag generated properly? Without form tags, required wont' work. Can you give a link or attach a screenshot of HTML in console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152004/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-vikas-kumar).

Comment: @Unbreakable you need to tell library to update validation rules by `$("form").data("validator", null);
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("form"));` after adding required attribute

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.MyRadioClass').on('change', function () {
    if($('input[name=SelectedRoleType]:checked').val() == "Referrer")
    {
        $('.MyTextBoxClass').removeAttr("style");
        $('.MyTextBoxClass #Email').attr('required','required');
    }
    else {
        $('.MyTextBoxClass').css('display', 'none');
        
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/" type="POST">
<div class="col-md-10 MyRadioClass">
    <input class="js-radio" id="SelectedRoleType" name="SelectedRoleType" type="radio" value="JobSeeker"> Job Seeker
    <input class="js-radio" id="SelectedRoleType" name="SelectedRoleType" type="radio" value="Referrer"> Referrar
</div>
        
<div class="col-md-10 MyTextBoxClass" style="display:none;">
    <input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="">
    
    
</div>
<input type="submit" value="test submit">
</form>
```

Here's your tested working code. Let me know if this worked!

Comment: Your solution works, I have added my complete code in the edit section. Why my code does not work. :-|

Comment: You need to add attribute like " $('.MyTextBoxClass #Email').attr('required','required');" not this : $('.MyTextBoxClass').css('required');

Comment: Bilal, when I inspect element, I am seeing the required attribute set properly. The issus is even then Iam able to submit the form

Comment: So, it's not about "Not being able to correctly add the required attrbute. After making some changes to my original code I was able to add the required attribute but still I am able to submit my form.

Comment: Okay, Could you please share at what line you are opening and closing form tag? I had to add form tag at the starting point. This could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely clean this up a little. Some ideas:

1. Using the input names as selectors (performance hit, but negligible in this use case)
2. No need to remove the required attribute when hiding the text input
3. Use a ternary instead of a if/else to save a line (up to you if this is less readable)
4. Chain the show() and attr() calls together

So based on the above, we'd be left with something like this:

```
$('[name="SelectedRoleType"]').on('change', function(e) {
  e.target.value === "Referrer"
    ? $('[name="Email"]').show().attr('required', true)
    : $('[name="Email"]').hide()
});
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ke4p37cy/

Answer (score 0):

Note, there are duplicate `id`s within HTML at Question at `id="SelectedRoleType"`. `id` of element in `document` should be unique. Substitute setting `"SelectedRoleType"` at `class` attribute at HTML.

You can use `.toggle()` to set `display` of `element` to `block` or `none` using `.index()` of currently clicked `<input type="radio">` element

```js
$(function() {
  $(".js-radio").on("click", function() {
    $("#Email").toggle(!!$(this).index())
  })
})
```

```css
#Email {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-10">
  <input class="js-radio SelectedRoleType" name="SelectedRoleType" type="radio" value="JobSeeker"> Job Seeker
  <input class="js-radio SelectedRoleType" name="SelectedRoleType" type="radio" value="Referrer"> Referrar
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
  <input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" required>
</div>
```