# submit the form without Page Refresh not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

plz add my code not working

i want user create post without refresh page on page accueil
// code html for form (title , text)

```
<form class="posting" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

<input type="text" name="title" class="title-input" placeholder="Quelle est votre question... ?"
autocomplete="off">

<textarea name="text" id="text" class="textarea" cols='60' rows='8' ></textarea>

<button class="btn-ajouter" type="submit" onclick="get()" name="ajouter" value="ajouter">ajouter</button>         
</form>
```

// code php create post (user)

```
if(isset($_POST['ajouter']) && !empty($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['title']) )
{
  $texte = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
  $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);

 $stmt=$connect->prepare('INSERT INTO

  publications(title_post,post) VALUES(?,?) ');

  $stmt>execute(array($texte,$title)); 
 }
```

// code display result (page accueil) (page accueil)

```
<div id="result">
 <?php 
  $stmt = $connect->query('SELECT *FROM publications ');

  while($row=$stmt->fetch() )
    {
      echo $row['title_post'] ; 
      echo $row['post'];
 ?>
</div>
```

// code ajax

```
     function get(){
      var result ;
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
      result = new XMLHttpRequest();

      else

      result = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

      result.onreadystatechange = function()
       { 
      if(result.readyState == 4 & result.status == 200)              
            document.getElementById('allpost').innerHTML = 
                                                      result.responseText;
       }

                  result.open('POST','accueil.php',false);
                  result.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-
                   form-urlencoded');
                  result.send();


               }
```

Comment: you can change submit button to html button and write a onclick() function for the button and call the ajax call in the onclick function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop form refreshing page on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit)

Comment: you are not passing any data in AJAX call.

Comment: **Possible duplicate of [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest).**

Answer (score 1):

First, there's a typo in your create post execute command.  You need -> not just > .

Second, you need to send data in your send command.  This can be handled manually, or simply setup the FormData object:

```
var form = document.getElementById("formID");
var data = new FormData(form);
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "form_processing.php");
xmlhttp.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

your ajax method should looks like this, because you are not passing any data to it now. (don't forget to add id to the title input)

```
var data = {
  title: document.getElementById('title').value,
  text: document.getElementById('text').value
};
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'accueil.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **not listen** for a click event on the submit `button`, because a user could submit the form without clicking (TAB + ENTER). Instead, you should listen for a submit event directly on the `form` element.

```
<form class="posting" method="POST" onsubmit="get(event);" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Now, when the `form` will be submitted, you will receive the event variable inside your `get()` function, so you have to change your function parameters into `get(e)`.

Inside your function body, you will now be able to use the **preventDefault** method:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: and add the data to the post request. :) the refresh of page is a secondary problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change some part of code, and try to add a listener, and after, you prevent default

#### Define id, or something to get/fetch the form object in DOM

At this code, I use `id="myForm"` to get/fetch the object and after add listener.

`<form id="myForm" class="posting" method="POST"enctype="multipart/form-data">`

and now you'll get the object

`document.getElementById("myForm");` or if you are using jQuery `$("#myForm")`

#### Set listener (Using default JavaScript)

If you aren't using `jQuery` you can use this code to add the listener

`element.addEventListener("submit", yourCallbackFunction(event), false);`

#### Set listener (Using jQuery)

`element.submit(yourCallback(event))`

#### Now just prevent default from event

`event.preventDefault()`

#### Do in your way your AJAX submit

I hope I was helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML Submit should be set up like this for Ajax.

```
<button class="btn-ajouter" type="button" onclick="myGetFunction();" name="ajouter" value="ajouter">ajouter</button>
```

and set an id for your title input

```
<input id="title" type="text" name="title" class="title-input" placeholder="Quelle est votre question... ?">
```

This is how your Ajax should look You had some structural issues.  Notice i got the form elements and made a string to pass to your php.

```
var request = false;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject){
request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
function myGetFunction(){
if(request){
request.open("POST", "calls/accueil.php");
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
document.getElementById('returnKeys').innerHTML = RequestObject.responseText;}}
var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
var data = title+'|'+text+'|';
RequestObject.send("data=" + data);}
return false;}
```

You should have one PHP page do the processing like this.

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
list($title, $text) = explode('|', $data);
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
if($title == '' || $text == ''){
if ($title == '') { $error['title'] = 'Username is Required.'; }
if ($text == '') { $error['text'] = 'Password is Required.'; }
$response = "Username and Password are Required to Continue.";
echo $error['title'];
echo $error['text'];
echo $response;
exit();
} else {
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
$title = htmlspecialchars($title);
$stmt=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO publications(title_post,post) VALUES ('".$title."', '".$text."'"));
$stmt>execute; 
$stmtb = $connect->query('SELECT * FROM publications ');
while($row=$stmtb->fetch() )
{
$mydata = $row['title_post'] ; 
$mydata .= $row['post'];
}
}
}
echo $mydata;
```