# button acting strange and reloads the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, button

I've created a button in this context:
[image]

And I have a javascript function expecting the click to make a request to the server:
[image]

But something weird happens when I hit the button, the page reloads it all and don't take the action expected. Thank you all in advance, im gettin crazy with this.

When I put an alert to check if the button is triggered I get an error:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, is there a chance you can copy and paste the code here instead of screenshots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a chance that you get this behavior because of the `form` tag. Try to remove the form tag and try again.

Maybe this can also help you:
[Stop form refreshing page on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit)

Comment: Omg... I can't believe thats the problem... Its solved! Thank you. But one last question, its better to get rid off the form tag or use te "preventDefault()" function?

Comment: @R.Quintal as @Marcel Ennix suggested in his comment, you can just add `type="button"` to you button and it shouldn't submit the form natively

Comment: yes, that's what I've done and It works! Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Try insert: type="button" inside the button tag. Otherwise it will be a submit button (when inside a form tag).