# how to stop reload the page after submit?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have that code that make me download images from other wepsite to my wepsite and after a click on submit the page is reload. I want to stop page from reload.
the code I put it in some plugin in wordpress.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a26nb.png)

```
the code that I put in the plugin 
<form action="zip.php" method="POST">
<h2 class="inputmanga"> manga name:</h2></p>
<input type="text" name="name">
<h2 class="inputmanga"> image url:</h2></p>
<input type="text" name="img">
<h2 class="inputmanga"> image numper :</h2>
<input type="text" name="num"><br><br>
<input class="sumbitmanga" type="submit" value="Get!">
```

the php code that I put in separate folder

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
 $my_save_dir = "manga/".$_POST['name'].".zip";
 $zip->open($my_save_dir, ZipArchive::CREATE);
 $num = $_POST['num'];
 for ($i=1; $i <= $num ; $i++) { 
  $url_to_image = $_POST['img'].$i.'.jpg';
  $download_file = file_get_contents($url_to_image);
  $zip->addFromString(basename($url_to_image), $download_file);
  }
  $zip->close();
  echo $my_save_dir . "  Download completed successfully";
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to submit an ajax request to send the email without reloading the page. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$('.submitmanga').click(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'zip.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        // pass required data here
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        alert('successfully sent');
    }               
});
```

});

The form will submit in the background to the zip.php page which will need to handle the request.

Comment: how to do that i dont have knowledge of java

Comment: @abbasameer This is not JAVA but Javascript, You can add it as the end of the body of your html file, But make sure you load the JQuery library for the $ sign to work.

Answer (score 0):

This  is a repeated question, you do that  by listening on the  submit event.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19454346/11028815

Comment: I have no knowledge of Java