# Automatically refresh the page after saving the edited form in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I save the form. I call the function `onSave`. Web page is automattic refresh

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {

            todos: [{
                id: 1,
                date: '2019-12-09',
                description: 'Hello'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                date: '2019-11-10',
                description: 'World'
            }],
            isEditing: false,
            id
        };
    this.update = this.update.bind(this)
    }

    update(id, time) {
        this.setState({
            todos: this.state.todos.map(el => (el.id === id ? Object.assign({}, el, {
                time
            }) : el))
        });

        setEditing = (id) => {
            this.setState({
                isEditing: !this.state.isEditing,
                id: id
            })
        }

        render() {
            return ( < div >
                < ul > {
                    this.state.todos
                        .map((todo, index) =>
                            < Todo key = {
                                todo.id
                            }
                            index = {
                                index
                            }
                            todo = {
                                todo
                            }
                            setEditing = {
                                this.setEditing
                            }
                            update = {
                                this.update
                            }
                            />
                        )
                } < /ul> < /div>
            );
        }
    }
```

** Todo **

```
        class Todo extends Component {

            state = {
                startDate: new Date(),
                description: '',
            }

            handleChange = (date) => {
                this.setState({
                    startDate: date
                });
            }

            handleDescription = (evt) => {
                this.setState({
                    description: evt.target.value
                })
            }

            saveEdit = () => {
                const {
                    description, status
                } = this.state;

                this.props.update(this.props.id, {
                    description,
                    status,
                    date: this.state.date
                })
            }

            onSave = () => {

                const {
                    description
                } = this.state;

                this.props.update(this.props.id, {
                    description, date: this.formatDate()
                });

                this.setState({
                    isEditing: false
                })
            }

            componentDidMount = () => {
                const {
                    todo
                } = this.props;

                this.setState({
                    description: todo.description,
                    startDate: new Date(todo.date)
                })
            }

            render() {

                return ( < div > {
                        this.state.isEditing

                            ? ( < EditForm handleChange = {
                                this.handleChange
                            }
                            description = {
                                this.state.description
                            }
                            startDate = {
                                this.state.startDate
                            }
                            handleDescription = {
                                this.handleDescription
                            }
                            onSave = {
                                this.onSave
                            }
                            onCancel = {
                                this.onCancel
                            }
                            />): ( < li >
                                < div > {
                                    this.props.todo.date
                                } < /div> < div > {
                                    this.props.todo.description
                                } < /div> < button onClick = {
                                    this.setEditing(this.props.todo.id)
                                } > Edit < /button> < /li>
                            )

                        } < /div>
                    )
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using event.preventDefault()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

Adding event.preventDefault() should do the trick.

```
onSave = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
                const {
                    description
                } = this.state;

                this.props.update(this.props.id, {
                    description, date: this.formatDate()
                });

                this.setState({
                    isEditing: false
                })
            }
```

Also, similar posts.
[Stop form refreshing page on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit)
[Automatically refresh the page after saving the edited form in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56789258/automatically-refresh-the-page-after-saving-the-edited-form-in-react/56789376#56789376)