# Why does the page reload after submitting form? (React/Netlify/react-recaptcha)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha, netlify

***Problem:*** I am using the `react-recaptcha` library to show a Google reCAPTCHA v2 in my ReactJS form. The UI seems to look fine, but when I submit the form, the page reloads and I never receive any form submissions on Netlify.

***Attempt:*** Removing the reCAPTCHA and the form works fine, and I receive the form submissions in Netlify, so the problem has something to do with the reCAPTCHA.

I am using **`create-react-app`** for react website.

Following the Netlify [form documentation](https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/#custom-recaptcha-2-with-your-own-settings), I have [signed up](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html) for a reCAPTCHA v2 API key pair from Google, and set two environmental variables within the site settings.

[My Netlify environmental variables settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Do8.png)

The relevant code is available in this gist: [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/byeung2019/cbd37365f2112ac8ba47d5bd0b0419a3)

In theory, putting this in html:

```
<script
  src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"
  async
  defer
></script>
```

And this in the Form.js:

```
 <Recaptcha
     sitekey={process.env.REACT_APP_SITE_RECAPTCHA_KEY}
     theme="dark"
 />
```

should have made it work, but I'm not sure what is causing the page to reload after the form submits.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Edit: This is **not** an `e.preventDefault()` problem, because I am using Netlify to handle form submissions. Upon form submission, it will redirect the user to a default form success page. The problem here is once I add the reCAPTCHA inside the form, the page reloads without sending me the form data nor to the redirected page. And that is even after I add a `e.preventDefault()` handler on form submission.

Comment: You are describing the behavior that is supposed to happen. Forms submit the page. if you want to not submit then call `preventDefault` on the event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop form refreshing page on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit)

Comment: This is not an e.preventDefault() problem, because I am using Netlify to handle form submissions. Upon form submission, it will redirect the user to a default form success page. The problem here is once I add the reCAPTCHA inside the form, the page reloads without sending me the form data nor to the redirected page. And that is even after I add a e.preventDefault() handler on form submission.

Answer (score 1):

Like described in the comments, forms submit the page, thats the intended behavior. If you want to avoid this then call `preventDefault` on the event.

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
```

and the handler would look like this

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Your code has typos. Can't determine if your answer is correct or not.

Comment: @posfan12 care to elaborate on what the typos are? are you referring to the fact that I didn't write out the rest of the code for `handleSubmit` or something? surely you can infer the correct syntax... my answer was an example, to show where to place `event.preventDefault()`. The React docs have [plenty of examples](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) if you're looking for full syntactical help

Answer (score 0):

**What worked for me**

In Netlify, I added a `REACT_APP_` prefix version of the env var(s).

E.g. if I had these env vars:

1. SITE_KEY=123
2. SITE_SECRET=abc

I added these:

1. REACT_APP_SITE_KEY=123
2. REACT_APP_SITE_SECRET=abc

So in total in the Netlify dashboard I would have:

1. SITE_KEY=123
2. SITE_SECRET=abc
3. REACT_APP_SITE_KEY=123
4. REACT_APP_SITE_SECRET=abc