# Reactjs - I am trying to handle and event in a popup, but the popup is not being rendered as it should after an event execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I have a function that is called when the user clicks a button on a popup of a reactjs applicatiomn.

```
sendAnswer = () => {

      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(this.answer);
      const data = { answer: this.answer };
      const requestInfo = {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          headers: new Headers({
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }),
      };

      fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5d920649310000d48110ccd7', requestInfo)
      .then(response => {
          if(response.ok) {
            console.log('ok')
            this.setState({sentAnswer: true})

              return response.json()
          }
          throw new Error("Erro ao enviar a resposta...");
      })
      .catch(e => {
          this.setState({ message: e.message });
      });
    }
```

I have this code here in render():

```
{!this.state.sent ? (
            <textarea type="text" id="form10" className="md-textarea form-control" rows="3" onChange={e => this.answer = e.target.value} placeholder="Insira a sua resposta aqui" />
                                ) : ( 
            <Alert color="primary" className="text-center"> Message was sent! </Alert>
                                )}
```

However, the popup is not refreshed. The sendAswer function is being called and executed, but I need to refresh the popup and show the message "Message was sent!" after its execution.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.setState({sentAnswer: true})
```

This is the state you are updating but your condition is base on `!this.state.sent`.

Either change the condition to `!this.state.sentAnswer` or `this.setState({sent: true})`. I believe this is what it is and was just mistyped.

Comment: It usually does. It also happens to me more times than I can count.