# Redirecting on successfull AJAX call does not work

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have this AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "json": JSON.stringify(json) },
    url: hostUrl,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status) {
            window.location.href = data.redirect;
        }
        else {
            alert(data.message);
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

`data.redirect` contains URL, which user should be redirected to, but unfortunately, it does nothing.

Can anybody tell me what is the issue?

I tried to redirect to other ASP controllers, or even `www.google.com`, but nothing works.

This is JSON response:

```
{"status":true,"message":"successful authentication","redirect":"/Users"}
```

I am working with ASP.NET Core, I set breakpoint in `Users` controller, to which I am redirecting. It was hit just once. After that one redirect, it stops to redirect to that page. But even if breakpoint was hit, it didn't redirect to returned view.

It's like just getting refreshed

**EDIT**:

HTML, which appeared to be important:

```
<form method="post">
    Login: 
    <input name="loginName" type="text" /> <br/>
    Password: 
    <input name="passwordInput" type="password" /><br/>    
    <button id="authBtn" onclick="handleLogin()" value="Get message"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Using the debugger built into your browser, set a breakpoint on the `if (data.status)` line and another one on the `console.log(err)` line. Then do whatever it is that triggers the ajax. One of those breakpoints will be hit and stop execution of the code. If it's the one on `if (data.status)`, hover your mouse over `status` and the browser will show you its value. It would appear that whatever that value is, it's falsy (so it's `0`, or `""`, or `false`, etc.).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I checked it, it's `true`

Comment: Maybe something else is happening, but the code you posted works for me with the response you shared (ie it redirects to the specified URL).

Comment: @haldo - No, you don't. Relative URLs will get expanded as normal.

Comment: Okay, so if it's `true` and you step foward, do you see the assignment to `href`? What value is being assigned? Etc., etc. We can't solve this for you, it's a debugging problem.

Comment: Try using `assign()` instead:`window.location.assign(data.redirect);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `ajax` call was placed in `form` element in HTML, which was sending HTML request as well.

When AJAX call and redirect was handled, it came back to original HTTP request amde by `form` element and returned to original page, thus it looked like it was refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the form submission. Change button type from `submit` to `button`

`<button type="button" id="authBtn" onclick="handleLogin()" value="Get message"></button>`

Comment: You mention it or not, a button inside a form tag will be a submit type by default. You need to explicitly change it to type button if you need to avoid the submit behaviour

Comment: Check vicky gonsalves answer in here 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit