# Want to send a message when pressing the enter but reloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have built a chat feature in React.js. It works but the page is reloaded when sending the message. Better to be able to send a chat when pressing the enter, but it should not be reloaded. How can the app works to send a message with enter without reloading.

```
<form>
  <input
    name="chat"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Enter message"
    value={this.state.chat}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
  <button
    onClick={() => this.handleSend(chat)}
  >
    <span>Send</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

If I don't use `<form />`, it won't be reloaded. But it doesn't work to send a message when pressing the enter.

Comment: Default `type` of `button` is `submit`. You need to chose a different button type (`button`), or prevent the default event action from within you revent handler function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop form refreshing page on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

**1.)** Change the type of the button to `button` instead of the default `submit`.

**2.)** Use `e.preventDefault()` function after the form submits to prevent the default action which is to reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the type of the button other than Submit .Or handle the default behavior as `e.preventDefault()`