# why is the form value disappearing from the console log?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

In the below code, I am trying to `console.log` the form input value when a button gets clicked. However, upon the button click, the value is only getting logged momentarily before disappearing.
why is this happening and how to resolve it?

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
  const listItem = document.querySelector("input").value;
  console.log(listItem);
});
```

```html
<body>  
  <form action="">
    <input type="text">
    <button class ="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit"> ADD </button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop form refreshing page on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit)

Comment: You submit your form upon clicking. Thus, it disappears. Change the button type from submit to button

Answer (score 4):

When submitting a form, the browser sends a request to the server and refreshes the page. To disable this behavior, you can use `event.preventDefault()` when clicking the button

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  const listItem = document.querySelector("input").value;
  console.log(listItem);
});
```

```html
<body>  
  <form action="">
    <input type="text">
    <button class ="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit"> ADD </button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have explained that submitting a form reloads the page. But that doesn't really address the question about the console log.

Go to the Developer Tools settings, and in the Console section check **Preserve log upon navigation**. Then you won't lose log messages when the page reloads because of the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

This is because browser reloads on the form submission. And your data is lost.
To prevent this simply use "event.preventDefault()" function after your log statement after passing "event" as a parameter in the event listener function.
Like this:

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function (***event***) {
const listItem = document.querySelector("input").value;
console.log(listItem);
***event.preventDefault();***
});