# Prevent method Post form from refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, forms, form-submit, submit-button

I have a form with **method Post** and **action** with URL, when I click button to submit, after submitting, it gets refreshed. I want to prevent from being refreshed.

I used:

`onsubmit=";return false"` in form tag but it did not submit the form.

Also tried:

`type="button"` in save button but it did not submit.

**my Form:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ url('panel/admin/webscraper') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="text" name="subcategory" value="{{$subcategory}}">
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: In that case you should use AJAX requests

Comment: well if you want to submit the form with normal HTML, the page is going to refresh.

Comment: @epascarello using Laravel, any JS or Php method to try?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit This maybe help you

Comment: @DineshMsd Since I have action with URL your suggested Link did not work for me

Comment: https://www.webtrickshome.com/forum/how-to-stop-form-resubmission-on-page-refresh

Comment: Ajax would be the best solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a submit event to your form and then use preventDefault to prevent refresh, after that do your AJAX

Set id to form

```
<form id="noRefreshForm" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ url('panel/admin/webscraper') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Finally select this form and then use preventdefault

```
document.getElementById("noRefreshForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
// this line prevents refresh the page
  event.preventDefault()

// do your AJAX
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just disable button after click:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ url('panel/admin/webscraper') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="text" name="subcategory" value="{{$subcategory}}">
<button type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use method="dialog"

```
<form onsubmit="postFunction()" method="dialog"></form>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action

Comment: This does not submit the form, but triggers an event instead

Comment: that depends on postFunction(ajax)

Comment: Does it depend on the return value of the handler?