# Alert message doesn't show on submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm just starting out learning HTML/JavaScript. I've got a form that when submitted it should show the input data back to the user, I've tried both an alert and the .html() method and neither seem to display the information back.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        function displayInfo() {
            let product = ($('#productName').val());
            let quantity = parseInt($('#qty').val());

            if ($('#delivery:checked').val() == 'y'){
                let delivery = "Delivery required";
            }
            else{
                let delivery = "Delivery not required";
            }
            var info = "Product name: " + product + "<br>" + "Quantity: " + quantity + "<br>" + "Delivery?:" + delivery;
            $("#info").html(info);
            
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example page</h1>
    
    <form onsubmit="displayInfo(); return false;">
        <p>Enter the name of the product you want to buy: <input type="text" id="productName"/></p>
        <p>Enter the quantity you want to buy: <input type="text" id="qty" /></p>
        <p>Do you require delivery? <input type="checkbox" id="delivery" value="y" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Place order" /></p>
    </form>

    <div id ="info"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and also

```
            alert("Product name: " + product + "<br>" + "Quantity: " + quantity + "<br>" + "Delivery?:" + delivery);
```

Comment: Form submitting refreshes the page by default. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have set the path to the `jQuery` library incorrectly. Also, you need to declare `delivery` on the same level as you are using it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script>
        function displayInfo() {
            const product = ($('#productName').val());
            const quantity = parseInt($('#qty').val());
            let delivery = "Delivery not required";
            if ($('#delivery')[0].checked){
                delivery = "Delivery required";
            }
            const info = "Product name: " + product + "<br>" + "Quantity: " + quantity + "<br>" + "Delivery?: " + delivery;
            $("#info").html(info);
            
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example page</h1>
    
    <form onsubmit="displayInfo(); return false;">
        <p>Enter the name of the product you want to buy: <input type="text" id="productName"/></p>
        <p>Enter the quantity you want to buy: <input type="text" id="qty" /></p>
        <p>Do you require delivery? <input type="checkbox" id="delivery" value="y" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Place order" /></p>
    </form>

    <div id ="info"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope following Answer will help you

**I have simplified your code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        function displayInfo() {
            event.preventDefault();
            let product = ($('#productName').val());
            let quantity = parseInt($('#qty').val());
            let delivery = $('input#delivery:checked') ? "Delivery required" : " Delivery not required";
            
            var info = "Product name: " + product + "<br>" + "Quantity: " + quantity + "<br>" + "Delivery?:" + delivery;
            $("#info").html(info);
            
            alert("Product name: " + product + ", Quantity: " + quantity + ", Delivery?:" + delivery);
            
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example page</h1>
    
    <form onsubmit="displayInfo();">
        <p>Enter the name of the product you want to buy: <input type="text" id="productName"/></p>
        <p>Enter the quantity you want to buy: <input type="text" id="qty" /></p>
        <p>Do you require delivery? <input type="checkbox" id="delivery" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Place order" /></p>
    </form>

    <div id ="info"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**I have did following changes in your code**

**1st Change:** I called jQuery CDN library (If you download jQuery library into your loacl, you can ignore this change)

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
```

Changed to

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**2nd Change:** changed the delivery variable scope, now it's in block scope so you can't access delivery variable outside the condition

Now I have change this condition into  **Conditional ternary operator**  and I get the variable from that.

More details about Javascript Scope [Click Here](https://dev.to/sandy8111112004/javascript-introduction-to-scope-function-scope-block-scope-d11)

More details about Conditional (ternary) operator [Click Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
if ($('#delivery:checked').val() == 'y'){
 let delivery = "Delivery required";
}
else{
 let delivery = "Delivery not required";
}
```

Changed to

```
let delivery = $('input#delivery:checked') ? "Delivery required" : " Delivery not required";
```

You also can use like this

```
let delivery = "Delivery not required";
if ($('#delivery')[0].checked){
  delivery = "Delivery required";
}
```

---

**3rd Change:** You can't use html tag inside of alert popup, so I remove all `<br>` tags

```
alert("Product name: " + product + "<br>" + "Quantity: " + quantity + "<br>" + "Delivery?:" + delivery);
```

Changed to

```
alert("Product name: " + product + ", Quantity: " + quantity + ", Delivery?:" + delivery);
```

---

**4th Change:** To avoid page refresh in form submit I used `event.preventDefault();`

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Learn More About Event.preventDefault() [Click Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

---

**5th Change:** I did following Html change

```
<form onsubmit="displayInfo(); return false;">
```

Changed to

```
<form onsubmit="displayInfo();">
```