# How can i fix : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"?

Tags: javascript, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaBEM.png)

I tried some solution to fix this error like put `<script> below </body>` but it didn't work. So how can i fix this. Here is my code. I want to know what is my fault so i can fix this when i met this error again. Thanks first

```
<body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="login">
                <h2><strong>Login</strong></h2>
                <br>
                <form id="info" ac>
                    <label>Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Input username" name="username" id="first">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Input password" name="password" id="seconde">
                    <div>
                        <button id="bt">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <script>
document.querySelector("bt").addEventListener("click",function(check){
    var a = document.querySelector("#first").value;
    var b = document.querySelector("#second").value;
    if(a=="admin" && b=="123456"){
        alert('Login Success!\nRedirecting to next page');
        document.querySelector("#info").action="nextpage1.html"
    }else{
        alert('Login failed!\nIncorrect username or password');
    }
})
        </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: You probably meant `document.querySelector("#bt")` to select by ID. Just `"bt"` would be looking for a `<bt>` element which doesn't exist

Comment: I'd strongly recommend adding `type="button"` to your `<button>` so it doesn't [submit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19454310/283366) when you click it

Comment: @Phil oh it really word, well the error here just my broken eyes. Thanks.

Comment: Happens to all of us.

Comment: @Noo, is my answer incorrect, since you rated it down?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error is showing because you must specify that you are selecting what (class/id) 
in your code you forgot to put a # before id name

```
document.querySelector("#bt")
```

you also can use

```
document.getElementById("bt")
```

Answer (score -1):

As Phil suggested above, `document.querySelector` will look for whatever you have mentioned inside it.

Since you have `bt` it'll look for the tag `<bt>`.

So if you wanna select an id `bt` make sure to use `#` before the name of the actual id.

or If you wanna select a class, don't forget to use `.` before the name of the actual class name.

Example:

- Selecting with ID - `document.querySelector("#bt")`
- Selecting with ClassName - `document.querySelector(".bt")`

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:
Update 1: In input, changed the id from seconde to second
Update 2: In document.querySelector, added # with bt.

```
<body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="login">
                <h2><strong>Login</strong></h2>
                <br>
                <form id="info" ac>
                    <label>Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Input username" name="username" id="first">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Input password" name="password" id="second">
                    <div>
                        <button id="bt">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <script>
document.querySelector("#bt").addEventListener("click",function(check){
    var a = document.querySelector("#first").value;
    var b = document.querySelector("#second").value;
    if(a=="admin" && b=="123456"){
        alert('Login Success!\nRedirecting to next page');
        document.querySelector("#info").action="nextpage1.html"
    }else{
        alert('Login failed!\nIncorrect username or password');
    }
})
        </script>
 </body>
```