# How to stay at the same page and the same location (after scrolling) after submitting post request with Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

I am counting the views on a post on my website and for that I have created a 'more' button (but styled as a link) after some text so that the user clicks on that and the view count increases.
The button submits a post request and I increment the view count in the database.

The problem is that I have 2 separate pages (which might increase in the future) that display the posts and they both have this 'more' button which submits the post request to the same route. I want the user to click the button and stay on that same page on that same location but in express we are required to res.redirect or render 1 page which isn't possible in this case. I tried to redirect to ('/'), but this goes only to one of the 2 pages that I talked about and not the current page. Moreover, when redirecting, the extra paras shown on clicking that button also vanishes, basically going to the original orientation. I am happy to change the entire logic of this function as long as you cannot find any solution with this one...

```
router.post("/clicked-more", ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let secId = req.body.clicked_more

    const sec = await XXX.find({
      _id: secId
    }).lean();
    sec[0].views++

    await XXX.findOneAndUpdate({
      _id: secId
    }, {
      views: sec[0].views
    });
    res.redirect('/')

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    //   res.send(err)
    res.render("../views/error/500");
  }
});
```

This is one of my 2 pages (hbs-handlebars).
(2nd one has the same function as this one)

```
<form action="/clicked-more" method="post">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="startPara">{{stripTags (truncate body 200)}}<span class="dots">...</span></p>
    <span class="content">
      <p>{{stripTags (truncate body 400)}}</p>
    </span>
    <button type="submit" name="clicked_more" value={{_id}} class="link-button buttonReadMore"
      onclick="readMoreFunction(this)">more</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is my 'read more' function

```
function readMoreFunction(el) {
  var parent = el.closest(".wrapper")
  var dots = parent.querySelector(".dots");
  var contentText = parent.querySelector(".content");
  var btnText = parent.querySelector(".buttonReadMore");
  var startPara = parent.querySelector(".startPara");

  btnText.style.display = "none";
  startPara.style.display = "none";
  dots.style.display = "none";
  contentText.style.display = "inline";
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're wanting to make an AJAX request, not a form submission with a refresh. Usually, you'd use a JSON API and use JS to submit the request here using `fetch`, wiith `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop form refreshing page on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit)

Comment: @ggorlen I tried both the solutions, the accepted solution didn't work but the other solution was working halfway only. Basically the 2nd solution is to write <form onsubmit="return false"> but this doesn't let the form submit so the post request doesn't go through and the view count doesn't increase

Comment: Yeah, you probably want the `document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", e => {e.preventDefault(); fetch("your JSON endpoint");})` pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Use a library like AJAX or AXIOS to make your http request without refreshing your page OR if you can't do that, send the window.scroll functions current value in the request and return it as the header after the request has been made. Then use the urlSearchParams to retrieve the scroll bars previous location.