# How to prevent html form refresh on submit?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

Hello after searching and trying a lot , i am not able to find the issue so that I am seeking your help to solve my issue.

Here I have a form while clicking on submit button it should call the javascript function and **should **not redirect or refresh the page**** .

Here I want to send mail using SMTPJS with attachments by filling the form and choosing the image once the form submitted it should call the `sendEmail()` function and mail should be send, but when i click on the submit button it's refreshing the page and it's not working accordingly.

```
<form onsubmit="sendEmail(); reset(); return false">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-floating">
                  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileupload" required>
      <label for="phone">Upload file</label>
               </div>
         </div>
                                        
         <div class="col-12">
             <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 py-3" type="submit" style="background-color: #0e2e50;">Upload</button>
     </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <script>
            function sendEmail() {
                var file = event.srcElement.files[0];
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
       reader.onload = function () {
           var dataUri = "data:" + file.type + ";base64," + btoa(reader.result);
                Email.send({
                    Host: "smtp.elasticemail.com",
                    SecureToken :"************"
                    To: 'mail@mail.com',
                    From: "mail@mail.com",
                    Subject: "Form Enquiry",
                    Body : "Sending file:" + file.name,
                        Attachments : [
                {
                    name : file.name,
                    data : dataUri
                }]
                }).then(
                    message => alert(message)
                );
            };
            }
        </script>
```

I think the issue is in this line 'var file = event.srcElement.files[0];' because from this line it's refreshing the page and a Question mark (?) is coming in the URL. ex.page.html?

One more thing if i am calling the `sendEmail()` function in the onchange event of the input type file then it's working fine, why so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop form refreshing page on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit)

Comment: No, preventDefault() is not working in my case @MatthewHerbst

Comment: `onsubmit="sendEmail(); reset(); return false"` — The `return false` should block regular form submission (and thus page reloading) unless the JS throws an exception. Have you checked the browser console to see if it does?

Comment: @Quentin there is an error in the console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'srcElement')"
this line -> var file = event.srcElement.files[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

## Typo

The first is a typo and is highlighted by the browser telling you:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing } after property list note: { opened at line 24, column 19

This exception is preventing the function from being created, so the `onsubmit` function errors when it calls it, and you never reach the `return false` that prevents the form submission.

**Read the error messages in the console in the browser developer tools**.

You are missing a comma between `SecureToken :"************"` and `To: 'mail@mail.com'`.

## Forms don't have files

You said:

> ```
> var file = event.srcElement.files[0];
> ```

Which gets the element that triggered the event (since it is a submit event, that is the `<form>`) and you try to read the `files` property from it.

The browser tells you this:

> Uncaught TypeError: event.srcElement.files is undefined

**Read the error messages in the console in the browser developer tools**.

The `files` property can be found on `<input type="file">`, not on the `<form>`.

You need to find the correct element:

```
var file = event.srcElement.querySelector('[type="file"]').files[0];
```

## Asides

To generally make life easier and avoid these sorts of issues:

- Use a linter, like ESLint, and an editor that can use it as a plug in
- Use a code formatter to indent code and help locate syntax errors
- Don't use intrinsic event attributes (like `onsubmit`); do use `addEventListener`
- Pay attention to what your debugging tools are telling you

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much for describing. now I understood .
Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Just change it a little bit:

```
<form onSubmit="sendEmail(event)">
...
</form>

function sendEmail(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

Comment: That will throw an exception because `event` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Quentin By adding the `event` as a parameter when you are calling the function you can define it

Comment: Yes, but your answer (before you edited it) didn't do that. After editing, your answer is now effectively the same as [this older one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73031525/19068) except you are reading the global event variable in a different place and passing it.

Comment: Well, yes, I said it was the same as the previous answer, not that it wouldn't work.

Comment: @SepehrAmirkiaee if i am adding event.preventDefault() its stop refreshing but it not able to read this line 'var file = event.srcElement.files[0];' i put a alert after this line its not working and the mail is not getting sent