# React, Typescript - update setState in another component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-q8csl5?file=App.tsx,Child.tsx)

I'm simply trying to update the useState in one component from another component.

Its sort of working here but doesn't work at all in my app

The app.tsx is like

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Child from './Child';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('Red');

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{value}</div>
      <div>
        <Child onNameChange={setValue} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And the child component like

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

const Child = ({ onNameChange }) => {
  const handleInputChange = React.useCallback(() => {
    onNameChange('blue');
  }, [onNameChange]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleInputChange}>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

The problems here are it keeps reloading after the button is pressed.

And in App.tsx it errors on `<Child onNameChange={setValue} />` with `'Child' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element.`

Can anyone explain how to get this working without these mistakes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop form refreshing page on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit)

Comment: This is not a react-specific problem. HTML form just reloads the page by default

Comment: yeah sorry I forgot the `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the default behavior of the `<form>` element, It makes a `GET` request, the value of the form inputs will be the url query parameters (in your case there is no input so you only see the `?` )

to solve this you can add this line to prevent this default behavior:

```js
  const handleInputChange = React.useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      onNameChange('blue');
    },
    [onNameChange]
  );
```

Comment: yeah worked that bit out

Comment: great, so this solves it all or there is still something ?
also , is the explanation clear ?

Comment: And in App.tsx it errors on `<Child onNameChange={setValue} />` with `'Child' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element.`