# Why is my HTML form refreshing instead of alerting once it's submitted, despite adding onsubmit="return false">? and is throwing some error?

Tags: javascript, html

Why is this simple HTML and Javascript not working?

I just need to alert once the form is submitted. It instead is refreshing and throwing an error and sometimes throwing a CORS error also, if use type as module.

HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="JavaScript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="addUser(); return false">
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" required /><br />
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="" required /><br />
      <label for="lname">Phone number:</label><br />
      <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone" value="" required /><br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript File

```
function addUser() {
  console.log('Hello');
  alert('Hello');
}
```

Comment: @NicoHaase no, I have already added <form onsubmit="return false">

Comment: `type="JavaScript"` is not a valid MIME type. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type) on what values you should use for `type`. You can remove the `type` attribute altogether if the script is JavaScript.

Comment: Instead of returning `false` you need to prevent the default behavior as shown in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19454346/3257622).

Comment: _Usually_ `return false` should work fine. I'm not sure if a blocking operation such as `alert()` breaks this, since it might take too long before `false` is returned. (Though in this case I think that calling `addUser()` will result in an error because the script isn't imported properly due to the `type` attribute. This error makes it so that `return false` is never reached.)

Comment: Ivar adding type as module makes it throw CORS error

Comment: @DNèp I never said anything about module. Either remove the `type` completely, make it an empty string, or set it to `text/javascript`. If your `src` is truly `src="script.js"` and `script.js` only contains what you show here, then it shouldn't cause any CORS issues. If your script is located elsewhere, or is making calls to external services, then that is a different problem.

Comment: @Ivar yes setting it to text/javascript fixed the issue. Thank you

Comment: @Ivar please write it as an answer, so that I can accept it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `type="JavaScript"` on your `<script>` tag. Because "JavaScript" [is not a valid JavaScript MIME-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#textjavascript), the block [will be treated as a data block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type#value) and wont be processed by the browser.

This means that your `addUser()` function is never loaded in. Calling it will cause an error meaning that `return false` is never reached and thus the form submission will not be prevented.

To fix it, either use the valid JavaScript MIME-type `text/javascript`. Or even better, omit the `type` attribute altogether.

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>
```